# jQuery POSTed null data to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a jQuery posting data to controller:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Api/MyDefaultApi/SaveElections",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(this.state.data),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (resp) {
                showAlert("success", resp);
            }
        }).fail((err) => {
                showAlert("danger", err);
        });
```

By the way, the "this.state.data" variable is an array like this:

```
[{prop1: "hello", prop2: "world", prop3: "!!"}, {{prop1: "hello1", prop2: "world1", prop3: "!!1"}, {{prop1: "hello2", prop2: "world2", prop3: "!!2"}]
```

Everything seems fine, except 2 problems here:

1. Server gave me 'Bad Request' Error 400. Even though the controller was called successfully.
2. Inside the controller below, the 'data' passed in is null. However, I can see that 'this.state.data' is not null.

   ```
   [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SaveElections([FromBody]string[] data) {
   try
   {
       //do something
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       //something went wrong
   }
   }
   ```

How can I resolve above 2 problems? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your posting a collection of objects containing 3 properties,  not a `string[]`

Comment: Is your JSON valid ? I think no. check here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Yeah, that isn't JSON. Also, remove `[FromBody]`, you don't need it so don't write it.

Comment: see my answer, your JSON is incorrect! you are wanting a string array in C#. Thus json needs to be either: `["string1","string1"]` or `{"data":["string1","string1"]}`

Comment: @rach8garg, OP has not shown the the JSON, they have show the javascript object which will be converted to JSON using `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 0):

On these type of errors, try using static data and see if it comes accros:

```
data: JSON.stringify(["this","is","a","test"]),
```

and also try:

```
data: ["this","is","a","test"],
```

If this works, your problem is in your javascript state object.

If this doesn't work. you can check your chrome developer console network tab and see what is actually send to the server.

### comment

your json seems to be an `array of Objects` or in c# terms `array of Dictionary` instead your C# expects an `Array of Strings`!

Answer (score 0):

Validate your JSON before sending.

Here is what your `this.state.data` object should look like.

```
[{
    "prop1": "hello",
    "prop2": "world",
    "prop3": "!!"
},
{
    "prop1": "hello1",
    "prop2": "world1",
    "prop3": "!!1"
},
{
    "prop1": "hello2",
    "prop2": "world2",
    "prop3": "!!2"
}]
```

Comment: Thanks. My question seems stupid but I am newbie in Web development and C#. 'JSON.stringify(this.state.data)' seems to produce valid json. But why it's still passing null value to controller?

Comment: Note you do not need to quote the property names - the `JSON.stringify()` method will do that if they are not quoted.

Comment: @Henrix And its your double `{{` which is invalid but I assume that is a typo. Your sending an array of objects, not strings which is why it will not bind - its needs to be `SomeObject[]` where `SomeObject` contains the 3 matching properties